# python arg escaping in shell commands (calling avconv)

Tags: python, shell, escaping

## THE PROBLEM (sending args to avconv that have weird chars)

Here's a function to convert a file using "avconv": I've tried any number of ways but, for the life of me, I can't get the quoting to work properly!

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
#from pipes import quote # this fails in the same way as shlex.quote.
# The following is copied from python 3.3 shlex.py and modified for 2.7 -----------------------------------
import re
#_find_unsafe = re.compile(r'[^\w@%+=:,./-]', re.ASCII).search
_find_unsafe = re.compile(r'[^\w@%+=:,./-]').search

def quote(s):
    """Return a shell-escaped version of the string *s*."""
    if not s:
        return "''"
    if _find_unsafe(s) is None:
        return s

    # use single quotes, and put single quotes into double quotes
    # the string $'b is then quoted as '$'"'"'b'
    return "'" + s.replace("'", "'\"'\"'") + "'"



def convert(from_fpath, to_path):

        from_fpath = quote(from_fpath)
        to_fpath = quote(to_fpath)

        cmd = ['avconv', '-i', from_fpath, to_fpath]
        print '--- avconv -i %s \t %s' % (from_fpath, to_fpath)

        try:
            #output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=False)
            output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
            print output
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
            print "Failed", str(e)
            print "Failed output:\n", e.output
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### The FAILURE via python

Here's some output of the failure...(for some reason the avconv program isn't recognizing the args (I tried also with '-i my_file' in one arg instead of 2).

```
--- avconv -i '/home/me/MEDIA/MUSIC_CONVERT/Zen/05 Je T'"'"'aime Mais.m4a'   '/home/me/MEDIA/MUSIC_CONVERT/CONVERTED/05 Je T'"'"'aime Mais.mp3'
Failed Command '['avconv', '-i', '\'/home/me/MEDIA/MUSIC_CONVERT/Zen/05 Je T\'"\'"\'aime Mais.m4a\'', '\'/home/me/MEDIA/MUSIC_CONVERT/CONVERTED/05 Je T\'"\'"\'aime Mais.mp3\'']' returned non-zero exit status 1
Failed output:
avconv version 0.8.3-6:0.8.3-6ubuntu2, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
  built on Oct  1 2012 12:57:14 with gcc 4.7.2
Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man avconv'
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: avconv [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

### The Same thing working without python

On the command line (ie in the shell), the command works:

```
$ avconv -i '/home/me/MEDIA/MUSIC_CONVERT/Zen/05 Je T'"'"'aime Mais.m4a'  '/home/me/MEDIA/MUSIC_CONVERT/CONVERTED/05 Je T'"'"'aime Mais.mp3'
avconv version 0.8.3-6:0.8.3-6ubuntu2, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
  built on Oct  1 2012 12:57:14 with gcc 4.7.2
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/me/MEDIA/MUSIC_CONVERT/Zen/05 Je T'aime Mais.m4a':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4A 
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: M4A mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2007-11-10 00:27:13
    title           : Je T'aime Mais
    artist          : Zazie
    album           : Zen
    genre           : Rock
    track           : 5/12
    disc            : 1/1
    date            : 1995
    gapless_playback: 0
    encoder         : iTunes v7.5.0.20, QuickTime 7.3
  Duration: 00:04:19.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 129 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2007-11-10 00:27:13
```

...etc...all ok!

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Nicolas' answer is correct, but I'd go further: DO NOT escape the file paths (Using subprocess means that all argument values get passed exactly as they are. The only reason for quoting in the shell is because arguments are normally split according to the location of spaces), and DO NOT use shell=True (this is for when you are passing a command that the shell must interpret, eg. 'echo foo|wc -l -' needs shell=True because it uses shell piping)

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't need to pass `shell=True` to `subprocess.check_output()` nor to escape the file paths in your `cmd` list.

Comment: Thanks: I thought I'd tried that combination but obviously not! The answer, as you rightly point out, is to use shell=False AND not to quote any of the arguments. Thank you very much for your help.